# ActiveCollab - Forgot admin password - cannot reset through phpmyadmin

Tags: password-hash, forgot-password, reset-password, activecollab

I am unable to reset the owner password for ActiveCollab v5.

Emails are not configured, so forgot password option is useless.

I have access to PHPMyAdmin, but am unable to reset the password.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting password directly in the database is not recommended. Instead, there's a command in ActiveCollab's command line utility that lets you set user's password. Navigate your terminal to a directory where ActiveCollab is installed and run:

```
php tasks/activecollab-cli.php user:set_password you@your-company.com
```

System will prompt you for a new password and set it.

If ActiveCollab's CLI tool complains that `user:set_password` command is not present, you are using an older version of ActiveCollab, and you should upgrade first. This can be done through command line as well. Here's the help article that goes into more details:

https://activecollab.com/help/books/self-hosted/upgrade